# In Artifactory, can I modify the target paths for AQL download results like I can when using patterns and placeholders?

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way to perform path manipulation against AQL results?  i.e. similar to how Placeholders can be used to modify a pattern's results when assigning the target path.

I am attempting to download files from a repository like so:
`my-generic-repository/myFolder/mySubfolder/(*)`
...becomes...
`C:\my\crazy\new\location\{1}`
...recursively, with the portion of the tree in (*) preserved as {1}.

My download spec looks like:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "aql": {
                "items.find": {
                    "repo": "my-generic-repository",
                    "path": {
                        "$match": "myFolder/mySubFolder/*"
                    }
                }
            },
            "flat": "false",
            "recursive": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

To run the query I do this:

```
cd C:\my\crazy\new\location
jfrog rt download --spec=MySpecFile.txt --include-dirs=true --quiet=true
```

I observe the following file-tree:
`C:\my\crazy\new\location\myFolder\mySubfolder\...`
...but I want the following file-tree:
`C:\my\crazy\new\location\...`

Setting `flat=true` causes the repository's contents to be flattened completely and all files drop into `C:\my\crazy\new\location` without their hierarchy, which is not useful to me either.

(I'll add more AQL query complexity once I get the basic download to work, which is why I wish to use AQL and not 'pattern')

(side-note:  I only get the files that are one subfolder deep or deeper within the specified path, not the files located exactly in the specified path, which is also making me scratch my head)

Comment: Target path manipulation using placeholders is supported in file specs only when using "pattern" and not "aql". What is the reason you prefer AQL over patterns? Which query are you not able to perform with patterns?

Comment: I would like to use $and and $or to create a query to find a collection of files based upon the value of multiple properties, and including a less-than-or-equal against a build-number as well.  Sort of like:  if (@PRODUCT==StoreApp and @BUILD==Dev) or (@PRODUCT!=StoreApp and @BUILD==Shipping) and @PLATFORM==WIN64 and @CHANGELIST<=53211 then download those files

Comment: I think we should add more complex properties operations to file  specs. Would you like to open a feature request for this under jfrog-cli 's GitHub repo?

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.